# Display JSON format data

Tags: php, json, codeigniter

When a retrieve the according data from the database then encode it as json then pass it to the view:

```
    $json_data = json_encode($x);
    $search_results['search_results'] = $json_data;
    $this->load->view('findquestions',$search_results);
```

If I display this in the view we get:

```
[{"question_title":"java"},{"question_title":"big java book"}]
```

How can the question_titles so "java" be extracted and presented as a url link or inside a table

Comment: You should send the data as a PHP array and loop through it in the view. If you are calling the above method via ajax then it is easy to interpret the JSON object within the .done() function.

Comment: How exactly do you need to access the data in the view? Do you need to access the results through javascript (i.e. you're loading the results via ajax) or are you generating the view through PHP and you can process the results directly with PHP?

Comment: @newfurniturey Im generating the view through php and I can process the results directly with php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're passing the json-string directly to the view and then process it (for display) through PHP, you should be able to use PHP's [`json_decode()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) to convert it into an object (or array) to use it in a more-friendly manner:

```
// use json_decode with `true` to get an associative array
$results = json_decode($search_results['search_results'], true);
```

You can now access the data either directly or within a loop:

```
// direct access
$title1 = $results[0]['question_title'];

// in a loop
foreach ($results as $result) {
    echo 'Title: ' . $result['question_title'];
}
```

For reference, using the sample-data supplied in the question, a `print_r()` of the data:

```
print_r($results);

Array (
    [0] => Array (
            [question_title] => java
        )
    [1] => Array (
            [question_title] => big java book
        )
)
```

Comment: thanks, is there a way I can make the titles a link, then when clicked display the information of the json data it belongs to

Comment: @sunrise3333 Of course, but you'll have to be more specific in your request. Are you saying that you want the title, such as `java`, to appear as a link (i.e. `<a href="some_page.html">java</a>`) and, when clicked, it displays the original json text (on a new page, in a popup window, under the link, etc)?

Comment: yes exactly that on a new page or popup which ever is easiest, I have already presented it a link

Answer (score 0):

To process the results in PHP

In your controller:

```
$search_results['search_results'] = $x; //store the array
$this->load->view('findquestions',$search_results); //pass the results as PHP array to view
```

In your view:

```
foreach($search_results as $result){
   echo $result['question_title'];
}
```